# What Time datatype should I use

Tags: c#, file-io, time

This seems to be a silly question but,
I have to read some data from a text file this data is

```
ID          Time          Value
Graph1      0:00          1.0 
Graph1      0:30          1.5
Graph1      1:00          2.0

or

ID          Time          Value
Graph1      0.00           1.0 
Graph1      0.50           1.5
Graph1      1.00           2.0
```

My question is what datatype should I use for Time, as 0.5 is 0:30, 1.8 is 1:48 and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5);
```